# Дубль контента во вкладке с описанием товара на woocommerce — почему?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на **wordpress+woocommerce**. (woo последней версии) 
Есть своя тема (тестировал с абсолютно чистой, там где только файлы *styles.css* и *index.php* и *single-product.php* скопированный с шаблонов плагина ) и поотключал плагины.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на странице товара по какой-то причине выводится дубль контента всего товара во вкладке с описанием.
С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Протестируй на нормальной теме, а не самопиське и увидишь что там всё нормальною ЗЫ. А на "чистой" не может быть "похожих товаров".

Comment: @SeVlad если заглянуть в шаблоны `woocommerce`, а именно в файл related.php, то там присутствует вот такой фрагмент кода, который на сайте и выводится
`<section class="related products">
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
</section>`
В файле локализации Related products переводятся именно как "Похожие товары", так что я с вами не соглашусь

Comment: И WC и сам WP имеют множество функций *под капотом*. А что (и как) выводить и отображать на фронте - епархя темы. Грубо говоря простейшая тема покажет чистый лист. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.90.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B: "Простейшая тема включает в себя только файл style.css"

Comment: @SeVlad  обнаружил проблему - заключается она в том, что в теме есть файл <b>single.php</b>, который управляет выводом страницы товара и других одиночных страниц.
Его можно перебить только, если поместить В КОРЕНЬ темы <b>single-product.php</b>, но шаблоны <i>woocommerce</i> берутся еще и из папки плагина и тем самым возникает дубль.. 
single-product.php же из папки вукомерса в теме не может перебить <b>single.php</b>
Пока не знаю как это обойти не переименовывая single.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ [здесь](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/single-product-is-using-single-php-not-single-product-php/)

Нужно в **functions.php** прописать следующую инструкцию:

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Смысл в том, что если в теме не задекларировать, что она использует *woocommerce*, то по умолчанию шаблоны будут браться не из папки *woocommerce* в теме как мы того ожидаем, а из корня, т.е. `single.php` будет приоритетнее по отношению к `single-product.php` в подпапке темы

Темы по умолчанию в этом смысле отличаются, т.к. **woocommerce** закладывает в них поддержку изначально.